# not a statement in Java

Tags: java

this program converts binary to decimal. And it outputs the solution to the console. At startup, it gives an error:

```
source_file.java:20: error: ';' expected
               int sum + = numArr [i];
                      ^
source_file.java:20: error: not assertion
               int sum + = numArr [i];
                                ^
2 errors
```

I have no idea what the matter is.
If it's not difficult, please write a solution.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Compiler version JDK 11.0.2

class Dcoder
{  
  public static void main(String args[])
  {  
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Write num");
      String str = in.nextLine();
      int[] numArr = Arrays.stream(str.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
      
      for(int i = numArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
          
          numArr[i] = numArr[i] * 2;
          
          int sum += numArr[i];
          
          if (i == 0){
              System.out.print(numArr[i]+" * 2 = "+sum);
          }
          else{
              System.out.print(numArr[i]+" * 2 + ");
          } 
      } 
  }
}
```

Solution method:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and initialize the variable sum outside the for loop.

if you intend to store the sum of previous iterations in the variable sum,you can declare the variable 'sum' outside the for loop.

Please refer the below code,

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = numArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
          
          numArr[i] = numArr[i] * 2;
          
          sum += numArr[i];
          
          if (i == 0){
              System.out.print(numArr[i]+" * 2 = "+sum);
          }
          else{
              System.out.print(numArr[i]+" * 2 + ");
          } 
      }
```